# How can I tell ubuntu to ignore mouse movements while clicking?

Tags: mac, trackpad

I've got a Macbook Air and am trying out ubuntu on it.

One thing that is really annoying is the behavior of the trackpad. Macs have those click-pads, where you have to press down the whole trackpad for a click.

This works, but ubuntu doesn't ignore the movement while clicking. This leads to moving the mouse pointer a few pixels every time I try to click, which is really annoying.

Is there a setting to make ubuntu ignore movement while clicking?

Comment: This is annoying on my X220 as well.